# Export test jar with maven one jar plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I've used `maven-one-jar` plugin , exported runnable jars and used them.
Can I export a test-one-jar containing the junit test classes along with the other dependencies using this plugin?

What changes should I make in the pom(.xml) configuration?

Comment: Why do you need a test-jar with all dependencies? Integration tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise: I want to run the test suite from terminal and with cron.I also have a test runner class(with a main method) that I want to use as the main class.

Comment: Usually unit tests will run during the build and not via cron. This is usually done by a CI environment like Jenkins, Hudson, Travis-Ci or TeamCity etc. Furthermore it sounds more and more like integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to create a test-jar is simply using the maven-jar-plugin like this:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```